# Is there a non-Safari Apple Web browser for the Ipad / iPhone / iPod?

Tags: browsers, iphone, ipad, apple

I know Safari is the default Web browser on the current iPad / iPhone / iPod.

But was there a non-Safari **official Apple made** Web browser for these platforms in the past?

If so what are they and when they were used (so I can test my site with these browsers)?

Comment: Best way to test Apple devices on your website is to buy one ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Mobile Safari is the only browser that has ever been offered by Apple for iOS.

There are third-party browsers, but even those are required to use the core iOS WebKit rendering engine. The differences they provide are primarily UI-oriented, or things like a "private browsing" mode.

Comment: I do believe that Opera Mini uses it's own engine.And I would assume now that Google has forked Webkit, they will try to do the same. Wether they will be successful, I don't know.